# Is it possible to use "System.Data.DataTable" with 1000 columns as DataSource of "system.windows.forms.dataGridView"?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have no problems to fill the "System.Data.DataTable" with 1000 columns(no errors appears for now), but when I try to bind it to DataGridView this error message appears:

```
.NET runtime exception: Sum of the columns' FillWeight values cannot exceed 65535.
```

The error appears here:

```
"system.windows.forms.dataGridView".DataSource = "System.Data.DataTable"
```

The same problem exist when only "system.windows.forms.dataGridView" is used, but it can be solved using:

```
DataGridViewColumn.FillWeight = 1
```

when the columns are created and added to the DataGridView.

Is there a way to solve the problem when the DataTable is used as DataSource of the dataGridView?

Comment: Have you tried to  setting DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false? This will allow you to add the columns manually.

Comment: But why? No user wants 1000 columns.

Comment: @DaveS, when I use DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false no columns and rows are added to the dataGridView. When it is true the dataTable is bind to the dataGrid, but the error appears.

Comment: A `DataGridView` can have a maximum of `65,534` columns with a `FillWeight` value of 1. You could try to set `e.Column.FillWeight = 1` in the `ColumnAdded` event. But this is just in theory.

Comment: @Jimi, yes I know this and in the first post I wrote that FillWeight = 1 is a solution when the dataGridView is used(and it is filled with DataGridViewColumn). But what I do is to fill a dataTable with columns and rows. Then this dataTable is used as dataSource for a dataGridView and here is the problem - I can add 1000 rows to dataTable, but when the dataTable is set as source of datGridView the error occurs.

Comment: I wrote that comment because it wasn't clear whether the `FillWeight` was set on the `ColumnAdded` event, or setting a `DataGridViewColumn` property (directly, as a template, etc.). You *could* **try** to set a `FillWeight` value in the event when a `DataTable` is used as DataSource. This *could* work, in theory. But the `DataGridView` designers will most surely tell you that the object is not designed for this. It's supposed to host a ~300 max columns. Worth a try, though.

Comment: @Jimi, if I am right the DataTable first have to be added as a DataSource. All events are fired after that. But the error occurs before all the events.

Comment: Well, out of curiosity I've tested it and it actually can hold more than 1000 columns (tested with 2000 - it takes some time to fill up). Anyway, you can pre-build a Column template with `FillWeight = 1` and `AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None`. Set `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`. If you don't set the latter to false, it will load just 644 columns (at least, for me => VS 15.8.4 FW 4.7.1). This, however, says nothing about what will come next (stability, OutOfMemory exceptions and so on).

Comment: BTW, if you want the source code used for the test, just comment back.

Comment: @Jimi, yes please. I have no idea how to do what you already have done.

Comment: Here you go. I have a doubt  though. What language are you using? I posted it in `C#`, but looking at the snippets you posted, it appears more like `vb.net`. I can translate it, if that's the case (and it's really needed).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to test a `DataGridView` tolerance for mistreatment.
It adds `1000` `Columns` to the grid and 2 rows of data.
As described in the comments, I also tried it with `2000` `Columns` and, well, mission accomplished. Even though it takes its sweet time to complete this task.

**Note that this is not supported**.
A `DataGridView` is not supposed to have that number of `Columns`.
And no data model should have this kind of view.
Consider it a stress test for an UI object, to see where it breaks.

```
int MaxColumns = 1000;

//Create and a DataTable and add [MaxColumns] Columns
DataTable dt = new DataTable("TestTable");
dt.Columns.AddRange(
    Enumerable.Range(0, MaxColumns).Select(idx => 
        new DataColumn("Column" + idx.ToString(), typeof(string))).ToArray());

//Add 2 DataRows with [MaxColumns] values to the DataTable
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = Enumerable.Range(0, MaxColumns).Select(idx => "Value A" + idx.ToString()).ToArray();
dt.Rows.Add(row);
row = dt.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = Enumerable.Range(0, MaxColumns).Select(idx => "Value B" + idx.ToString()).ToArray();
dt.Rows.Add(row);

//Define a CellTemplate for the DataGridViewColumn template
DataGridViewCell ColumnCellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell {
    Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() {
        WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False,
        NullValue = string.Empty
    }
};

try
{   //Do not auto generate the columns, otherwise the control will stop the process
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    //Create a [MaxColumns] DataGridViewColumn array
    DataGridViewColumn[] ColumnArray =
        Enumerable.Range(0, MaxColumns).Select(idx =>
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {
                HeaderText = "Column" + idx.ToString(),
                DataPropertyName = "Column" + idx.ToString(),
                CellTemplate = ColumnCellTemplate,
                AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None,
                FillWeight = 1,
                DisplayIndex = idx
            }).ToArray();

    dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(ColumnArray);

   //Bind the DataTable and show the data.
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I will test it as soon as possible(I am at 24h shift at work right now) and will compare the times of execution. Since the dataGridView is not supposed to have such amount of columns is there a similar control that can handle 1000+ columns 1000+ rows fast and reliable?

Comment: The number of rows is not that relevant. This is what these controls are for and they're optimized for this. One thousands of columns is unseen. You'll have to find different ways. Testing and trying and smashing your digital face on this matter will cause a different solution to present itself at some point.

Comment: @miauu  Well, what happened then? Did you try to fill it up to the limit? Did it blow up at some point?

Comment: now there is no problem to add 1000 columns. I did not noticed any issues so far.

Comment: @miauu I was wondering whether you went down the hard path and tried with 65K :) Never mind, I was just curious.